# PHP - How to crop a image?

Tags: php

I am making a social media and I'm echoing profile pictures this way (code beneath), but I need to rescale the images that the users upload before echoing them. Either that or resize them before they get uploaded to the server.

Does anyone have some suggestions?

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, fname, profilePicture from users");
$stmt->execute();


$out = "";

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $picture = "<img src='profilePictures/$row[2]'>";
    $out .="<a href='profile.php?user=$row[0]'> $picture $row[1] </a> <br/>";

}
echo $out;
```

Answer (score 2):

The most common PHP library for this type of thing is imagemagick https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php. It should be fairly easy to do the manipulations with that.

When the users upload the photos you can save a smaller version as a thumbnail or profile pic (as well as the original if you'll need it later).

Comment: Definitely use this package. It's very, very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice library called [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/), which can both utilize PHP's ImageMagick- and GD-extensions as drivers. Here's a very basic example:

```
Image::make('path/to/image.jpg')
       ->resize(320, 240)
       ->save('path/to/ouput/image.jpg');
```